# One keystroke in emacs undo

Tags: emacs, undo

Recently emacs started undoing multiple keystrokes on one undo. I don't like that. I don't want that. I seem to remember it from the past and then it stopped or somehow I stopped it. How can I stop that? If I delete one too many characters, I want to be able to undo that one. If I type one too many characters, I want to be able to undo that. Currently it undoes some random number of changes. I don't want that.

Comment: Emacs uses a timer to store the recent changes.  You an put this on the `post-command-hook` for every key stroke if that is really what you want to do.  See `undo-auto--boundary-timer` and `undo-auto--boundary-ensure-timer`.  Or, you could change the saving timer interval -- it looks like it is set to 10 seconds -- I think this is the relevant line of code:  `(run-at-time 10 nil #'undo-auto--boundary-timer)`.

Comment: @lawlist: Please submit that as an answer. Remember: comments can be deleted at any time, and comments are not available for global search (AFAIK).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed something's changed: in the past, undo records for consecutive single-character insertions (with `self-insert-command`) were amalgamated (in groups of 20), but in Emacs-25, this was extended to single-char backward deletions with `delete-backward-char`.

The size of those groups (`20`) was hardcoded in C, and is now hardcoded in Elisp (in `undo-auto-amalgamate`).  So while it's still hardcoded, it's easier to override it without compiling your own Emacs.

Looking at the code I suspect you might be able to disable this amalgamation business with:

```
(advice-add 'undo-auto--last-boundary-amalgamating-number
            :override #'ignore)
```